# Why would ajax:success only work on 1 specific page on the entire application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this code to clear a very simple form. The callback for the `ajax:success` event works only on 1 page. If I am on any location like `/lists/:id` the code runs fine and even though this is global it just won't run on any other page

```
  $('#add_task_form').on "ajax:success", ->
    $('#add_task_title').focus().val ''
    $('#add_task_estimate').val ''
```

The partial for create renders fine but this code is never triggered and I wonder why?